# having trouble with this python code

Tags: python, python-3.3

i get this error and i have tried going through the posts available  on stack flow i do not still get the solution. this is the code

```
class  BankAccount:
    def  _init_(self,balance):
        self.balance  =  balance
    def  deposit(self,amount):
        self.balance  +=  amount
        return  self.balance
    def  withdraw(self,amount):
        if  amount>self.balance:
            print  "invalid  transaction"
        else:
            self.balance  -=  amount
            return  self.balance
class  MinimumBalanceAcccount(BankAccount):
```

// this is the error i get: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: If it's python3 it should be print('') and not print ''

Comment: Check whether you use only spaces (and not tabs here or there).

Comment: **After fixing this problem**, OP would presumably have run into issues due to the `_init_` typo (note the single underscores). Please also see: [Why isn't my class initialized by "def __int__" or "def _init_"? Why do I get a "takes no arguments" TypeError, or an AttributeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482298/)

Answer (score 0):

Its IndentationError.
complete the class definition.

```
class  BankAccount:
  def  _init_(self,balance):
    self.balance  =  balance
  def  deposit(self,amount):
    self.balance  +=  amount
    return  self.balance
  def  withdraw(self,amount):
    if  amount>self.balance:
        print  "invalid  transaction"
    else:
        self.balance  -=  amount
        return  self.balance

class  MinimumBalanceAcccount(BankAccount):
  def __init__(self):
    print "working"
```

Comment: I dnt think so. Im able to run the program, even if there is no blank lines between two class definition.

Comment: @ilim you don't need blank lines between anything in Python.

Comment: But you are not able to run it if a class def is not complete.