# Why isn't my class initialized by "def __int__" or "def _init_"? Why do I get a "takes no arguments" TypeError, or an AttributeError?

Tags: python, class, initialization, typeerror, magic-methods

**If your question was closed as a duplicate of this, it is because** you had a code sample including something along the lines of either:

```
class Example:
    def __int__(self, parameter):
        self.attribute = parameter
```

or:

```
class Example:
    def _init_(self, parameter):
        self.attribute = parameter
```

When you subsequently attempt to create an instance of the class, an error occurs:

```
>>> Example("an argument")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Example() takes no arguments
```

(In some versions of Python, the error may instead say `TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters`.)

Alternately, instances of the class seem to be missing attributes:

```
>>> class Example:
...     def __int__(self): # or _init_
...         self.attribute = 'value'

>>> Example().attribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'attribute'
```

You might also wonder: what do these exception messages mean, and how do they relate to the problem? Why didn't a problem occur earlier, for example, with the class definition itself? How else might the problem manifest? How can I guard against this problem in the future?

---

<sub>This is an *artificial [canonical question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose)* created specifically to head off two of the most common typographical errors in code written by new Python programmers. While questions caused by a typo are normally closed for that reason, there are some useful things to explain in this case, and having a duplicate target allows for closing questions faster. I have tried to design the question to be easy to search for.</sub>

<sub>See also [TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666353) for the opposite problem - writing `__init__` instead of `__int__` when trying to make a class that can be converted to integer.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is because the code has a simple typographical error**: the method should instead be named `__init__` - note the spelling, and note that there are *two* underscores on each side.

### What do the exception messages mean, and how do they relate to the problem?

As one might guess, a `TypeError` is an *error* that has to do with the *type* of something. In this case, the meaning is a bit strained: Python **also** uses this error type for function calls where the [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) (the things you put in between `()` in order to call a function, class constructor or other [callable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-callable)) cannot be properly assigned to the [parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter) (the things you put between `()` when writing a function using the `def` syntax).

In the examples where a `TypeError` occurs, the class constructor for `Example` does not take arguments. Why? *Because it is using the base `object` constructor*, which does not take arguments. That is just following the normal rules of inheritance: there is no `__init__` defined locally, so the one from the superclass - in this case, `object` - is used.

Similarly, an `AttributeError` is an *error* that has to do with an *attribute* of something. This is quite straightforward: the instance of `Example` doesn't have any `.attribute` attribute, because the constructor (which, again, comes from `object` due to the typo) did not set one.

### Why didn't a problem occur earlier, for example, with the class definition itself?

Because the method with a wrongly typed name is still syntactically valid. Only syntax errors (reported as `SyntaxError`) can be caught before the code runs. Python does not assign any special meaning to methods named `_init_` (with one underscore on each side), so it does not care what the parameters are. While [`__int__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__) is used for converting instances of the class to integer, and shouldn't have any parameters besides `self`, it is still *syntactically* valid.

Your IDE might be able to warn you about an `__int__` method that takes suspicious parameters (i.e., anything besides `self`). However, a) that doesn't completely solve the problem (see below), and b) the IDE might have helped you get it wrong in the first place (by making a bad autocomplete suggestion).

The `_init_` typo seems to be much less common nowadays. My guess is that people used to do this after reading example code out of books with poor typesetting.

### How else might the problem manifest?

In the case where an instance is successfully created (but not properly initialized), *any kind of problem* could potentially happen later (depending on *why* proper initialization was needed). For example:

```
BOMB_IS_SET = True

class DefusalExpert():
    def __int__(self):
        global BOMB_IS_SET
        BOMB_IS_SET = False
    def congratulate(self):
        if BOMB_IS_SET:
            raise RuntimeError("everything blew up, gg")
        else:
            print("hooray!")

>>> d = DefusalExpert()
>>> d.congratulate()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
RuntimeError: everything blew up, gg
```

If you intend for the class to be convertible to integer and also wrote `__int__` deliberately, the **last** one will take precedence:

```
class LoneliestNumber:
    def __int__(self):
        return 1
    def __int__(self): # was supposed to be __init__
        self.two = "can be as bad"

>>> int(LoneliestNumber())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __int__ returned non-int (type NoneType)
```

### How might I guard against the problem in the future?

There is no magic bullet. I find it helps a little to have the convention of always putting `__init__` (and/or `__new__`) as the first method in a class, if the class needs one. However, there is no substitute for proofreading, or for training.