# Python - Inheritence - Subclasses - TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, arguments, subclass

I have gone through several solution posted here for similar problem/Error, but it didn't help me to fix this issue.

```
class Employee:
    raise_amount = 1.05
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay


class Developer(Employee):
    raise_amount = 1.30
    def __int__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang):
        self.prog_lang = prog_lang
        super(Employee).__init__(first, last, pay)



print(help(Developer))
emp_1 = Developer('Iama','learner',2000 , 'Python')
```

I am getting error at last line as shown below. Could you help me figure out what is missing in my code?

```
 emp_1 = Developer('Iama','learner',2000 , 'Python')
TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't my class initialized by "def \_\_int\_\_" or "def \_init\_"? Why do I get a "takes no arguments" TypeError, or an AttributeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482298/why-isnt-my-class-initialized-by-def-int-or-def-init-why-do-i-get-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in the Developer class there has ****int**** rather than ****init****.

that is why the error raise as You have inherited the **Employee** class  into **Developer** therefor the **Employee** class ****init**** method is inherited into **Developer**

that is why the Employee **init** method has only **(self, first, last, pay):** argument to accept, and you are passing the the
**Developer('Iama','learner',2000 , 'Python')** is passing the 5 including self and the developer class has the ****init**** of **Employee** class therefor the error raise.

```
class Employee:
    raise_amount = 1.05
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay


class Developer(Employee):
    raise_amount = 1.30
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang): # rename __int__ to __init__ it is auto suggestion issue you have made 
        self.prog_lang = prog_lang
        super(Employee).__init__(first, last, pay)



print(help(Developer))
emp_1 = Developer('Iama','learner',2000 , 'Python')
```